# Align two plots in R (plot + image.plot)

Tags: r

I have a figure composed of two plots, a line plot and an image plot. [Here](http://ubuntuone.com/7YYXEzDs9tkIsh9UoD5XNW) is an example

My problem is that the image (bottom) is not aligned with the x axis in the top plot. Given that the image is a projection of the line, i would like to align them.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I am using basic stuff, here is the simplified code,

```
layout(matrix(seq(1,2), ncol = 1, byrow=T)) #,heights=c(0.5,0.25,0.25))
par(mar=c(5, 5, 3, 3), cex=mycex)

plot.default(X,Y,type=typ,pch=pc,col="black",axes=F,xlab="",ylab="",main="",xlim=c(0,P),ylim=c(0,max(Y)))
#other lines and polygons of top plot
axis(1); axis(2); title(xlab=xtitle,ylab="mean Y",main="")
image.plot(t(as.matrix(Y1)), col=jet.colors, axes=F, main="")
```

Comment: From the ?image.plot I see that it takes `par(oma=c(...))`. So, worst case scenario, you could trial and error-align them by eye.

Comment: There are two major plotting systems in R: 'base' and 'grid' and  then 'grid' has two major variants: 'lattice' and 'ggplot2'. Without a working example to view, it seems likely there will be too much guesswork to support a specific response.

Comment: @DWin yes, you are right, i've edited the post although the code i am using is as simple as it gets...

Comment: not reproducible yet: (1) `image.plot` is in the `fields` package: (2) what are `X`, `Y`, `Y1`, `mycex`, `typ`, `pc`, ... ?

Comment: thanks, ended up using the fastest solution by changing par between the plots